# IIS 500.19 on Windows 7

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, visual-studio-2012

I recently migrated all of my projects from an old computer to a newer system running Windows 7 64 Bit edition.  I am now attempting to get an ASP.NET site up and running locally but I keep getting an error:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

When I go through Visual Studio 2012's ASP.NET Configuration tool, there are no errors being reported - this only happens when I actually attempt to run the project.  I tried switching from 64 bit mode to 32 bit mode, enabling 32 bit applications in 64 bit mode, setting the Application Pool's identity and IIS Users Group to full control over all files - nothing is working.

Has this happened to anybody and, if so, how did you fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: No more detailed error information on the page or in the event viewer?

Comment: Checked this? : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things to consider.

1. Did you have any modules installed in IIS on the old system?  i.e. URL Rewrite, etc.

If so, either remove the sections in the config that they would reference (probably a bad idea, the modules were installed for a reason) or reinstall the modules on the new system.

1. The Application Log in event viewer will tell you exactly what line in the web config is faulting.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out - URL Rewrite was it!  I completely forgot about it as it been so long!